# what are the disadvantages refurbished ibm tape drives?

Tags: storage, ibm

Hello every one i m working in a company they wanna buy tape driver storage for IBM but they considering it must be Refurbished and i suggest new one i need information about advantage and disadvantages of refurbished tape drive storage thanks and advanceA

Comment: Assuming they can get the same capacity drive reconditioned as new, with a good support contract on it, I don't see any problem with reconditioned.  The usual problem is that you can only get older generation drives reconditioned, since they flood the market when new, higher-capacity drives are introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Pros: Cheaper (big savings), warranty, might look as a brand new tape.

Cons:  Not the original retail packaging. Possible cosmetic defects(scratches, dents etc). It is somewhat of a lottery.

Comment: Refurb typically have similar or same warranty on them.